# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar diccionarios en una lista dependiendo del valor de cierta key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

Tengo cierta lista con diccionarios, la cual es la siguiente:

```
packs = [
          {'Type':'t-vod', 'Definition':'SD', 'Price': 800},
          {'Type':'t-vod', 'Definition':'HD', 'Price': 800},
          {'Type':'t-vod', 'Definition':'SD', 'Price': 500}
        ]
```

Y lo que necesito es, comparando aquellos packs que tienen igual "type" y "definition" necesito quedarme con el que tiene menor precio, es decir debería quedar:

```
packs = [
          {'Type':'t-vod', 'Definition':'HD', 'Price': 800},
          {'Type':'t-vod', 'Definition':'SD', 'Price': 500}
        ]
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: El código que publicas tiene errores de sintaxis y está incompleto. ¿Qué es `package`. Corregido, sólo cuenta la cantidad de entradas en el diccionario, no la suma de los valores.

Comment: Lo edite asi queda mas simple la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente se usan diccionarios para realizar estas operaciones.

El diccionario `menor` está indexado por la combinación de `Type` más `Definition`, y contiene el menor precio encontrado mientras se recorre la lista original.

En cada iteración del `for` preguntamos si la nueva llave existe. Si no es asi, generamos una entrada con el precio del producto actual.

Si la llave existe, comparamos el valor almacenado con el valor del elemento actual, cogiendo el menor de los dos.

```
menor = {}
for dicc in packs:
    key = dicc['Type'] + ":" + dicc['Definition']
    if key not in menor:
        menor[key] = dicc['Price']

    if dicc['Price'] < menor[key]:
        menor[key] = dicc['Price']
```

Para generar la salida en el mismo formato de la entrada, recorremos el diccionario `menor` reconstruyendo los datos:

```
nuevo = []
for key, value in menor.items():
    tipo, definition = key.split(':')
    nuevo.append({'Type': tipo, 'Definition': definition, 'Price': value})
    print(tipo, definition, value)
    
print(nuevo)
```

produce:

```
t-vod SD 500
t-vod HD 800
[{'Type': 't-vod', 'Definition': 'SD', 'Price': 500}, {'Type': 't-vod', 'Definition': 'HD', 'Price': 800}]
```

Comment: gracias por tu aporte me fue de utilidad!

Answer (score 1):

Una solución, si no tienes ninguna restricción, sería usar el módulo `Pandas` que es muy usado para el tratamiento de datos. Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd                   #importamos pandas

df_packs = pd.DataFrame(packs)        #Creamos un DataFrame
df_packs = df_packs.sort_values("Price").drop_duplicates(["Type", "Definition"])
```

**Salida:**

```
    Type    Definition  Price
2   t-vod       SD       500
1   t-vod       HD       800
```

Las dos primeras lineas son bastante sencillas, nos importamos la librería, y creamos una **tabla de datos** (`DataFrame`).

En esta linea `df_packs.sort_values("Price").drop_duplicates(["Type", "Definition"])` hace lo siguiente:

1. Con el método `sort_values("Price")` ordena los datos de menor a mayor según el precios
2. Después con el método `drop_duplicates()` lo que hace es borrar **las filas repetidas manteniendo las primeras**. Es decir, como lo hemos ordenado de menor a mayor, las filas con menor precio repetidas, **nunca serán borradas**.

Por último si quieres devolver el `DataFrame` a el formato diccionario, puedes hacer:

```
df_packs.T.to_dict().values()
```

Comment: gracias pero lamentablemente no puedo usar pandas por limitaciones del repo :(